# How to optimize this Tensorflow weighted average custom op

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a Tensorflow op to perform weighted average based on this paper https://thijsvogels.nl/kpcn/bako2017kpcn.pdf

The op is to compute the average value of a pixel in an image with the weights multiplied by the values of its neighboring pixels.

I would like to seek any recommendation to optimize this code as the current implementation is quite slow.

the inputs.shape() is [1, 740, 1300, 3]

the weights.shape() is [1, 720, 1280, 441]

```
def weighted_average(inputs, weights):
    with tf.name_scope("weighted_average", "weighted_average", [inputs, weights]) as scope:
        in_shape = inputs.get_shape().as_list()
        w_shape = weights.get_shape().as_list()

        n_channels = in_shape[3]
        xs = tf.split(inputs, n_channels, axis=3)

        pad = (in_shape[1] - w_shape[1]) // 2

        kernel_size = pad * 2 + 1

        for index in range(n_channels):
            x = xs[index]

            x_stack = []
            for i in range(kernel_size):
                for j in range(kernel_size):
                    x_stack.append( x[:, i:x.shape[1] - 2 * pad + i, j:x.shape[2] - 2 * pad + j, :] )

            x_stack = tf.concat(x_stack, axis=3)
            x = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(x_stack, weights), axis=3, keep_dims=True)

            xs[index] = x

        return tf.concat(xs, axis=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting `tf.device('/cpu:0')` to force the op to be calculated in CPU and using Eigen lib makes it much faster.

I think it might be related to all the tensor transforms if it is computed in GPU.

```
def weighted_averagex(inputs, weights):
    with tf.name_scope("weighted_average", "weighted_average", [inputs, weights]) as scope:
      with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        in_shape = inputs.get_shape().as_list()
        w_shape = weights.get_shape().as_list()

        n_channels = in_shape[3]
        xs = tf.split(inputs, n_channels, axis=3)

        pad = (in_shape[1] - w_shape[1]) // 2

        kernel_size = pad * 2 + 1

        for index in range(n_channels):
            x = xs[index]

            x_stack = []
            for i in range(kernel_size):
                for j in range(kernel_size):
                    x_stack.append( x[:, i:x.shape[1] - 2 * pad + i, j:x.shape[2] - 2 * pad + j, :] )

            x_stack = tf.concat(x_stack, axis=3)
            x = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(x_stack, weights), axis=3, keep_dims=True)

            xs[index] = x

      return tf.concat(xs, axis=3)
```